# My cat shake's her back legs when she is sleeping or just relaxing

Tags: cats

My cat shakes when relaxing and sleeping, she also licks her lips and then gets up and has some food. I always leave food out for her, can any one help or has anyone else had this. Three of the vets I went to, keep telling me nothing is wrong.

Comment: This is a duplicate.